# AWSGlue: Decrypt- large files(50GB) using pyhthon-gnupg

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, large-files, python-gnupgp

Context:
We are receiving files which are PGP encrypted , which needs to be decrypted in AWS Glue using pyhon-gnupg module

Issue:
AWSGlue with PySpark is able to decrypt files upto 2GB files but we are receiving large files up to 50GB and 1TB in S3 bucket, AWSGlue throws error like " command failed with exit code 10 "

How do we decrypt large files using AWSGlue PySpark and python-gnupg

Current Code:

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
gpg.import_keys(private_key)
with self._fs.open(s3FileSourcePath, 'rb') as fd:
  decryptedFile = gpg.decrypt_file(fd, passphrase=secret_dict['PassPhrase'])
```

Comment: Were you able to do it?